# Array from JS to PHP via AJAX only works after second button click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem passing a multidimensional array from JS to PHP.
I am using Ajax to do so but i only get the values after a second click on the button. I would like it to work on the first click.

This is for a project which uses the Google MAPS / PLACES / Geolocation API.
I am using PHP 7.1 on XAMMP.
I tried to set the ajax request to async : "false" but it didn't work.

Here's the JS Code.

```
$("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Google_DB_Insert.php",
            data: {Google_Lieferant: (Google_Lieferant)},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Here's the PHP Code :

```
$data = [];

if(isset($_POST['Google_Lieferant'])) {
$data = $_POST['Google_Lieferant'];
}
var_dump($data);
```

On the first button click i get this output in my chrome console :

```
array(0) {
}
```

On the secon button click i get this output in my chrome console :

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["reference_id"]=>
    string(27) "ChIJb5Iv7pF9uEcRZWdjpp0E0_U"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "51.84731"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(17) "6.613619999999969"
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Title"
    ["address"]=>
    string(43) "Adress"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(15) "Phonenumber"
    ["website"]=>
    string(29) "Website"
    ["gewerk"]=>
    string(26) "Name"
  }
```

and the rest of the array.

The object / array Google_Lieferant looks like this in the chrome console before i send it via ajax :

```
Array(10)
0: {reference_id: "ChIJb5Iv7pF9uEcRZWdjpp0E0_U", lat: 51.84731, lng:...
1:...
```

I am kinda new to webdev and would be glad to get a push into the right direction. Thank you!

Edit: Here's the HTML markup

```
    <div class="margin">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Suchkriterien</h2>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/images/Gruppe.jpg" height="70" width="408" alt="Logo" align="right">

  </div>
    <form target="Rueckgabe" method="post" action="Lieferantenkarte.php">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Handwerkwaehlen">Handwerk</label>
                    <div class="ui-widget">
                        <input id="gewerke" class="form-control txt-auto"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Standortwaehlen">Standort</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Standortwaehlen" name="Standort" placeholder="Standort eingeben" onFocus="geolocate()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Google Suche">Google suche aktivieren?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" >

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="Radius">Suchradius</label>
                <input type="range" id="Radius" name="radius" class="form-control" min="2" max="100" value="5">
                <span id="Radius_Wert"></span><a> km Radius</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <button  type="submit" name="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Suchen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <iframe  width="1000px" height="500px" name="Rueckgabe">

            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="legend"><h3>Legend</h3></div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is your button of the type 'submit'?

Comment: Make sure your `Google_Lieferant` JavaScript variable is populated before you try to send it to the server. Type the variable into your JavaScript console to see what it contains before your first click, and before your second click.

Comment: @Ultimater I think you are right. I am sending data to the google API and populate the JS Variable with the answer. Is there a way to populate my variable first and send it to my PHP script after it is populated? Without a second click?

Comment: @ennuira93 There should be a callback for the API when it's loaded that you can listen to. Check the documentation for wherever you found your code. Otherwise if you have no control how this Google_Lieferant variable is populated, you can try setting up an interval through setInterval or setTimeout to detect when this variable gets populated. When it's detected to be populated, then clear the interval and run your server notification code.

Comment: @Ultimater I got it working! Thank you very much